# MDM iOS App Distribution as a private app and Files app

Tags: mdm, files-app

After switching to MDM and private app distribution it became impossible to view the app folder in the documents directory using Files App.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what needs to be enabled/configured/changed to be able to access and view the folder using the Files App?

The following was attempted:
App Group for logged-in MDM account was added.
UISupportsDocumentBrowser was added